Auto-focus on sensor shift technology
I just wonder how the auto-focus working in sensor shift, I meant the sensor shift stuff was like stabilize the sensor as well as its move the lens too (like in iphone 12 upward), I just dont know how it work? where is auto-focus sensor lying on in camera module in Iphone? I confused
And why auto-focus sensor is in the hall sensor, I thought it was just an algorithm PDAF (phase detection auto focus) to sharpen the image not relevant to any sensor? Also sensor-shift has auto-focus sensor too, not what I see that sensor-shift just have 2 sensor to move (move X, Y direction and Z direction - at the same time) yet?

The depth of focus is measured in cm at the widest of apertures, sensor shift is measured in nanometers, and is usually parallel to the focal plane. With features like IBIS, pixel shift for HDR, etc. You're infinitely more likely to see subject movement causing blur than sensor articulation blur, and even with a macro lens at its minimum focusing distance, the sensor cannot move enough along the principle axis to render your image out of focus.
To put it another way, if you shoot handheld, you will move the camera more between exposures than the camera moves the sensor, by a huge factor.
